# Need the Index No of an Array List, by giving the certain text of the element String

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof, lastindexof

I want to get the particular index of the array list, by using only contained text. Say suppose,

I have arraylist as

```
Test = {"LabTechnician","SeniorLabTechnician_4","Pathologist","SeniorLabTechnician_6"}
```

If want the index nos of both the `SeniorLabTechnician`, i have to use the exact string in the `indexOf` and `lastindexOf` method. Like `Test.indexOf("SeniorLabTechnician_4")` and `Test.lastindexOf("SeniorLabTechnician_6")`

this is will get me the exact answer.. But instead of that,by using only prefix say like senior or some thing like, i want the exact same answer before..

Like
`Test.indexOf("Senior")` and `Test.lastindexOf("Senior")`...

Please suggest

Comment: iterate over every list element and compare them with ``contains`` instead of ``equals``.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the list and compare the elements with `contains`:

```
int indexOfContains(List<String> lst, String what) {
  for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
    //this will make the check case insensitive, see JAVY's comment below:
    //if(lst[i].toLowerCase().contains(what.toLowerCase())) {
    if(lst[i].contains(what)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;  
}
```

If you want something like `lastIndexOf` then just reverse the order in which the list is iterated.

Comment: hey fish you may remove your negative flag if my code is correct thanks

Comment: `lst[i].toLowerCase().contains(what.toLowerCase())`  - for case insensitive finding.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ then you would need to to ``lst[i].toLowerCase().contains(what.toLowerCase())``.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that part when typing!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to modify default behaviour of indexOf and lastIndexOf methods of ArrayList.

1. My solution is create a new class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList.
2. Override indexOf method
3. Override lastIndexOf method

   ```
   public class CustomArrayList extends ArrayList {

     public int indexOf(Object o) {
       if (o == null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
               if (get(i) == null)
                   return i;
       } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
               if(o instanceof String) {
                   if(get(i).toString().startsWith(o.toString())) {
                       return i;
                   }
               } else {
                   if (o.equals(get(i)))
                       return i;
               }
       }
       return -1;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List list = new CustomArrayList();
       list.add("LabTechnician");
       list.add("SeniorLabTechnician_4");
       list.add("Pathologist");
       list.add("SeniorLabTechnician_6");
       System.out.println(list.indexOf("Senior"));
   }
   ```

   }

I left overriding of lastindexof method for you.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.. It works great.. Implemented too..:) I have done for lastindexof also its working fine...

Answer (score -1):

```
private int getsearchPos(String searchvalue) {
  for(String hj : Test)
     {
         if(hj.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchvalue.toLowerCase()))
                      return Test.indexOf(hj);
     }
    return -1;
}
```

this should help.

Comment: He already stated that ``indexOf`` does not work for him because it finds the elements based on ``equals``. He needs ``contains``.

Comment: Regarding your edit: This only allows finding prefixes (which is no problem since it's what the OP wants). But using ``indexOf`` again is not good because it unnessecarily iterates over the list a second time.

Comment: otherwise you cant find position of word to solve this we need to take a variable count to iterate until condition is true so i used basic indexof here hey can you remove downvote as my logic is correct

Comment: That's my point. That variable doesn't exist in your code. Imagine a list of 1 million elements and the element that you look for is the very last one. Then your loop checks every element and then the ``indexOf`` checks all of them again. Very inefficient. And avoidable using a simple counter variable